# Finding classes which should be instances sparql; Finding classes with exactly 1 subclass

Tags: sparql, protege, rdfs, linked-data

It sounds quite simple but I have not managed to find a nice solution yet. I'm looking to find the classes in my ontology which have exactly one subclass.

So far I have approached it as follows:

```
SELECT (COUNT(?anything) AS ?count) ?class
WHERE {
GRAPH <> {

    ?class rdf:type owl:Class.
    ?class rdfs:subClassOf ?anything.
    ?anything rdf:type owl:Class.
   
} group by ?class
```

I should then theoretically be able to sort on count, and the results that have value 1 should have only have 1 subclass. However, when I execute this query, the counts do not correspond with what I expect at all e.g. my test case should return 1, which it does, but another class which doesn't have a subclass at all, also returns 1. And a class with 3 subclasses returns a count of 4.

in the image below, it should find that the highlighted classes have a count of 1.
[image: picture of class structure]

Comment: you have to omit the trivial cases: 1) any class is subclass of itself 2) `owl:Nothing` is subclass of any class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SPARQL query you're looking for would be something like

```sql
SELECT ?class WHERE {
  ?sub rdfs:subClassOf ?class
}
GROUP BY ?class 
HAVING (COUNT(DISTINCT ?sub) = 1)
```

As UninformedUser mentioned in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65995172/finding-classes-which-should-be-instances-sparql-finding-classes-with-exactly-1#comment116685151_65995172), though, if there is OWL inference available, there can be lots of answers that you might not be expecting, such as

```
owl:Nothing rdfs:subClassOf ex:YourClass
```

and

```
ex:YourClass rdfs:subClassOf ex:YourClass
```

If those keep the query from producing the kind of results you're looking for, you should add a filter like

```sql
SELECT ?class WHERE {
  ?sub rdfs:subClassOf ?class
  FILTER ( ?sub != ?class && ?sub != owl:Nothing )
}
GROUP BY ?class 
HAVING (COUNT(DISTINCT ?sub) = 1)
```

Comment: Thank you both! This helped immensly. I have now learned about "Having". I also did not know a class could be a subclass of itsself, so the filters are helpful.

Comment: Perhaps more telling and frustrating to me, the real problem was my declaration in the WHERE statement, if I had flipped this statement: ?class rdfs:subClassOf ?anything. I would have already gotten correct answers in my case, but it's good to know that this might not always be correct, hence the filters.

Comment: @robin yes, a class X is a sub class of Y when everything that has type X also has type Y. So, every class is a subclass of itself.  Typically we won't assert that directly, but an OWL reasoner will recognize it.